# Is it okay to directly read from Cassandra to surface information from a web application?

Tags: web, web-applications, cassandra, nosql

I'm using Cassandra as my primary data store for a time series logging application. I receive a high-volume number of writes to this database, so Cassandra was a natural choice.

However, when I try showing statistics about the data on a web application, I make costly reads to this database and things start to slow down.

My initial idea is to run periodic cron jobs that pre-compute these statistics every hour. This would ensure no slow reads. I'm wondering if there's another way to read from a Cassandra database and what is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with what your initial thinking.

How you store data in C*, and specifically how you select you Primary Key fields have a direct influence on how you can read data out.  If you are hitting a single partition on a table reading data out of a C* cluster is very efficient and is an excellent choice for showing data on a website.

In your case if you want to show some level of aggregated data (e.g. by hour) I would suggest that you create your partition key in such as way as to make it so all the data you want to aggregate is contained in the same partition.  Here is an example schema for what I mean:

```
CREATE TABLE data_by_hour (
  day text,
  hour int,
  minute int,
  data float,
  PRIMARY KEY((day, hour), minute)
);
```

You can then use a cron job or some other mechanism to run a query and aggregate the data into another table to show on the website.